# Data is not showing in recyclerview while adding to the file

Tags: android, json, file, android-recyclerview

I am trying to store the **json data** to the file.This is the code for creating directories and file.

```
      public void filecreation() throws IOException {
       File mediaStorageDir = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir() + "/" + 
      "Zerribelum");
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d("App", "failed to create directory");
            //  return null;
        } else {
            Log.d("Apppppp", "create directory");
            File textfolder = new File(mediaStorageDir, "Text");
            if (!textfolder.exists()) {
                textfolder.mkdirs();
                File newtext = new File(textfolder, "dummy.txt");
                stream = new FileOutputStream(newtext);
                bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stream));
           
            }
            File imagefolder = new File(mediaStorageDir, "Image");
            if (!imagefolder.exists()) {
                imagefolder.mkdirs();
            }
            File videofolder = new File(mediaStorageDir, "Video");
            if (!videofolder.exists()) {
                videofolder.mkdirs();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I want put the json data to the file.

```
      try {
        JSONArray mJsonTopicArray = mJsonObject.getJSONArray(AppConstants.APIKeys.TOPICS_LIST);
        for (int i = 0; i < mJsonTopicArray.length(); i++) {
            Topics mTopics = new Topics();
            mTopics.setId(mJsonTopicArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(AppConstants.APIKeys.ID));
            mTopics.setTitle(mJsonTopicArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(AppConstants.APIKeys.TOPICS));
            mTopics.setImage(mJsonTopicArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(AppConstants.APIKeys.TOPICS_IMAGE));
            mTopics.setDescription(mJsonTopicArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(AppConstants.APIKeys.DESCRIPTION));

            mTopicsArrayList.add(mTopics);
            bw.write(mJsonTopicArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(AppConstants.APIKeys.DESCRIPTION));
            bw.newLine();
        }
          bw.close();
         mCategoryListRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    mCategoryListRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mCategoryListRecyclerView.setAdapter(new ParallaxRecyclerAdapter(context, HomeFragment.this, mTopicsArrayList));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The probelm is if I have'nt add `bw.write` and `bw.close()` lines the data will display in **recyclerview**. But when I add this lines, data is adding to file but not showing in recylcer view. I want both to be done. What will be the problem?

> Note: public FileOutputStream stream;
>
> public BufferedWriter bw; Initialised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved,the issue is because of Nullpointer Exception.So handled using try catch.

```
           try {
                bw.write(mJsonTopicArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(AppConstants.APIKeys.TOPICS));
                bw.newLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your stacktrace, your code must be crashing and you arent noticing it because of try catch

Attach a debugger and check the items in the arraylist once the adapter is initialized. If items are present it will work